# Postges локали ru_RU.KOI8-R, ru_RU.UTF-8, Windows CP1251 и ICU

Tags: postgresql, utf-8

Пытаюсь разобраться в создании БД с русской локалью (LC_COLLATE и LC_CTYPE). В первую очередь интересует верная сортировка символов (...е,ё,ж...).

Изначально создал БД с LC_COLLATE и LC_CTYPE ru_RU.UTF-8 на windows

```
CREATE DATABASE x WITH OWNER = xx ENCODING = 'UTF8' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1 LC_COLLATE = 'ru_RU.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'ru_RU.UTF-8' TEMPLATE template0;
```

Однако начитавшись про возможные проблемы с переносом на linux решил посмотреть в сторону ICU, дабы не зависеть от OC, [нашел там](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/10/multibyte) 2 русские локали KOI8-R и Windows CP1251.

Отсюда вопросы:

1. Действительно ли возможны проблемы с переносом бд с данными на
   linux?
2. Чем KOI8-R отличается от Windows CP1251?
3. Почему ru_RU.UTF-8 нет в списке ICU?

P.S. Буду признателен просто за советы по общераспространенным практикам выбора локалей в комментариях.

Comment: http://utf8everywhere.org

Comment: @dIm0n это значит стоит использовать ru_RU.UTF-8 и не мучаться?

Comment: Значит стоит прочитать инфу по ссылке

Comment: @dIm0n я пробежался по заголовкам и не заметил там чего-то связанного с моими вопросами, не уточните на какие части документа нужно обратить внимание?

Comment: На все части стоит обратить внимание. Конкретно про базы данных там нет

Comment: Нет никакого смысла использовать кодировку отличную от UTF-8. Не знаю про какие проблемы с линуксом вы начитались, но во всём линуксе повсеместно используется тоже именно UTF-8

Comment: Ещё не знаю, какое «нет в списке ICU» вы имеете в виду, по по вашей ссылке для кодировки UTF-8 в столбце «ICU?» написано «Да»

Comment: @andreymal насколько я понимаю все указанные в вопросе кодировки - это utf-8. Про ICU - https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/icu-support-postgresql-10/

Comment: @ZiiMakc KOI8-R и CP1251 появились задолго до UTF-8 (и до юникода вообще) и не имеют к ней отношения. И они в 21 веке не нужны, потому что юникод и UTF-8 изобретены именно для их замены

Comment: @andreymal возможно я неверно выразился, меня интересуют только настройки LC_COLLATE и LC_CTYPE, не ENCODING. ENCODING конечно будет utf-8

Comment: @ZiiMakc тогда всё-таки стоит пояснить, какие «проблемы с переносом на linux» вы имеете в виду. Лично я о таких проблемах не слышал

Comment: Глянул сборку PostgreSQL в репозиториях Ubuntu и CentOS — собран с поддержкой ICU, так что как минимум в убунте и центоси проблем с icu collate не должно быть (но как его правильно прописать пусть лучше спецы по постгресу подскажут)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо, тогда я оставляю LC_COLLATE и LC_CTYPE ru_RU.UTF-8.